# CMake define new target by string processing existing $<TARGET_FILE>

Tags: cmake

I"m trying to modernize an older CMake script that essentially does the following to generate a libtool file:

```
get_target_property(target_location ${target} LOCATION)
get_filename_component(target_we ${target_location} NAME_WE)
get_target_property(target_deps ${target} LT_DEPENDENCY_LIBS)
# ...
# Get a bunch more properties...
# ...
set(la_target ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${target_we}.la)
# ...
# Do a bunch of file(WRITE...) file(APPEND...) etc
# ...
install(FILES ${la_target} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib)
```

You cannot get the LOCATION property from a target in modern cmake, and I can't figure out how to do get_filename_component() on a $ generator.

Using the generator in an add_custom_command() COMMAND statement only allows one line, so I can't set variables to do all the necessary get_target_property()/file(WRITE...) processing.

Alternatively I can add a COMMAND cmake -P script.cmake to run a script which can do all the string processing but can't define or reference targets, so I appear to be stuck.

EDIT: I'm using the Makefile generator, on macOS, the target in question is a shared library that's generated in the same project.

EDIT2: The error is:

```
The LOCATION property may not be read from target "mytarget".  
Use the target name directly with add_custom_command, or use 
the generator expression $<TARGET_FILE>, as appropriate.
```

Comment: `You cannot get the LOCATION property from a target in modern cmake` - Why? [Docs for CMake 3.10](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/prop_tgt/LOCATION.html) describes this property normally.

Comment: Huh, that’s interesting. The existing code errors in cmake 3.9 and tells me I can’t do that and should use generators instead

Comment: CMake gives warnings about reading the `LOCATION` property, because it was often "misused" and it doesn't work for multi-configuration generators like Visual Studio. And your example code does look like you're trying to do `POST_BUILD` steps in the configuration phase. That's not going to work.

Comment: What generator (Visual Studio, Makefiles, ...) do you use? What kind of target (executable, library, imported library, ...) is?

Comment: Yes sorry should have specified: I'm using the Makefile generator, on macOS, the target in question is a shared library that's generated in the same project.

Comment: The error I get is:

    The LOCATION property may not be read from target "mytarget".  Use the target
  name directly with add_custom_command, or use the generator expression
  $<TARGET_FILE>, as appropriate.

Comment: Hm, it is policy[CMP0026](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/policy/CMP0026.html) which generates given warning. The main problem with *LOCATION* property, as @Florian said, that it depends on configuration, so in case of multi-configuration generators, it is known only at *build* stage, not at *configuration*. However, accodrind to your code, you just need a **name** of the output file. Or even something, which will be unique for a target, like a target's name. Is it true? If you also need a prefix, you may take it from [PREFIX](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/prop_tgt/PREFIX.html) property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can to it like this:

- first use `file` command to expand generator expressions and render a level-2 template
- ... which is going to be rendered at build time by `configure_file`

Here is a sample project:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(location-test VERSION 0.0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

add_executable(foo foo.cc)

file(GENERATE OUTPUT blah.la.in INPUT blah.la.in.in)

configure_file(render-variables.cmake.in render-variables.cmake @ONLY)

add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/blah.la"
    COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}"
        -DPROJECT_BINARY_DIR="${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}"
        -DPROJECT_NAME="${PROJECT_NAME}"
        -DPROJECT_VERSION="${PROJECT_VERSION}"
        -P "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/render-variables.cmake"
    MAIN_DEPENDENCY "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/blah.la.in"
    DEPENDS "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/render-variables.cmake"
)

add_custom_target(
    make-la-la-la ALL
    DEPENDS "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/blah.la"
)
```

`blah.la.in.in` (2-levels of tempaltes %):

```
# This file going to be rendered by the following pipeline:
# - at CMake execution time it'll expand all generator expressions 
# (e.g. $<TARGET_FILE:foo>)
# - at build time, the `render-variables.cmake` script will substitute 
# CMake variables (like @PROJECT_NAME@ or @PROJECT_VERSION@)
```

write the template for your real `.la` file... `render-variables.cmake.in` is trivial as :

```
configure_file("${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/blah.la.in" "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/blah.la" @ONLY)
```

And finally a dummy C++ file `foo.cc`:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello Africa!\n";
}
```

Build it!

```
localtion-sample$ mkdir build/
localtion-sample$ cd build/
localtion-sample/build$ cmake ..
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gcc-bin/5.4.0/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /tmp/localtion-sample/build

localtion-sample/build$ make 
Scanning dependencies of target foo
[ 33%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/foo.dir/foo.cc.o
[ 66%] Linking CXX executable foo
[ 66%] Built target foo
Scanning dependencies of target make-la-la-la
[100%] Generating blah.la
[100%] Built target make-la-la-la

localtion-sample/build$ ll
total 52K
drwxr-xr-x 6 zaufi zaufi  320 Feb  9 22:35 CMakeFiles/
-rw-r--r-- 1 zaufi zaufi  287 Feb  9 22:35 blah.la
-rw-r--r-- 1 zaufi zaufi  300 Feb  9 22:35 blah.la.in
-rw-r--r-- 1 zaufi zaufi  11K Feb  9 22:35 CMakeCache.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 zaufi zaufi 1.5K Feb  9 22:35 cmake_install.cmake
-rwxr-xr-x 1 zaufi zaufi  14K Feb  9 22:35 foo
-rw-r--r-- 1 zaufi zaufi 5.0K Feb  9 22:35 Makefile
-rw-r--r-- 1 zaufi zaufi   89 Feb  9 22:35 render-variables.cmake

localtion-sample/build$ cat blah.la
# This file going to be rendered by the following pipeline:
# - at CMake execution time it'll expand all generator expressions
# (e.g. /tmp/localtion-sample/build/foo)
# - at build time, the `render-variables.cmake` script will substitute
# CMake variables (like location-test or 0.0.1)
```